# How to do incremental cron?

Tags: drush, cron

I have to manage a rather large site which has problem with cron (white space of death on cron.php and 'segmentation fault' in drush). I could not fix the ong standing problem. Someone has suggested to do the cron job in several steps whcih can also hopefully pinpoint the problematic tables. I am wondering how to do the incremental cron and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a simple script that calls [`module_implements`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7), ala

```
$modules = module_implements("cron");
print_r($modules);
```

or

```
drush php-eval 'print_r(module_implements("cron"));'
```

you will see all modules that implement [`hook_cron`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7).  You can then manually call each hook via drush

```
drush php-eval 'search_cron();'
```

and see what happens.

You could also potentially

- Clear the `{cache}` tables manually, `drush cc all`
- Clear the `{watchdog}` table, `drush wd-del all`
- Clear the `{sessions}` table, though this may lose sessions for active users
- Manually reindex search, `drush search-reindex; drush search-index`

These can be the stinkers if cron hasn't run successfully in a while, as can XML sitemap rebuilds, too.

Comment: Many thanks MPD, this is exactly the info that I was looking for. However in some cases, like drush php-eval 'voting_cron();',  I get 'Drush command could not be completed.' Any ideas to fix these too?

Comment: @alfish, Other than checking the Apacke error_log, I don't know what could be going on.  I am not terribly familiar with that module.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Elysia cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron).

That module allows you to configure each cron hook implementation separately and it allows provides you with information about how long each mean/max execution time of those hooks.